# Variadic Variables by Reference

Tags: php

I was hoping to create a method through which I could "bind" several variables by reference such that they can be reused to pass new data to an object, essentially doing the same thing that PHP's `mysqli_stmt->bind_param()` method does.

However, it does not appear to be possible to specify that variadic arguments should be by reference, as-such they are always passed by value.

To illustrate, consider this example:

```
class MyType {
    private $bound = [];
    public function bind(...$vars) {
        $this->bound = [];
        foreach ($vars as &$v) { $this->bound[] = &$v; }
    }
    public function echo() {
        foreach ($this->bound as $v) { echo "$v\n"; }
    }
}

$a = 'Wrong'; $b = 'Wrong'; $t = new MyType();
$t->bind($a, $b);
$a = 'Right'; $b = 'Right';
$t->echo();
```

What I want is for the output to be two lines saying "Right", rather than "Wrong". Currently I'm achieving this using the following nasty workaround for the bind method:

```
public function bind(&$var0, &$var1 = null, &$var2 = null, &$var3 = null, ...$overflow) {
    if (!empty($overflow)) { throw new Exception('Too many arguments'); }

    $this->bound = [&$var0];

    if ($var1 === null) { return; }
    $this->bound[] = &$var1;

    if ($var2 === null) { return; }
    $this->bound[] = &$var2;

    if ($var3 === null) { return; }
    $this->bound[] = &$var3;
}
```

But obviously this limits me to only the number of variables I am willing to define. This also has the side-effect that I can't pass values of `null` into the method (as it is misinterpreted as a non-existent argument).

What I'm wondering is whether there is another way I can achieve this that isn't so boilerplate heavy?

Comment: Do note that variadic by-reference parameters can be a pain to work with on the caller's side. In fact you'll find loads of questions asking how to dynamically call `mysqli_bind_param`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for variadic parameters by reference is:

```
public function bind(&...$vars) {
    ....
}
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cae2646ee1964c09d6a4cb0ebd3040176f53bec4)